# Extract python script from exe generated with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

Is it possible to get .py text file from .exe file generated with cx_Freeze? If yes, how can I prevent it when I generate exe? I don't want that somebody see my python code. Of course anybody will have access to bytecode, but it much harder to disasemblate it.

Comment: By default, only the bytecode is included by current (4.x) versions of cx_Freeze. But there are libraries like [meta](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/meta) that make decompiling bytecode fairly painless, so it doesn't really stop someone from finding out what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks! Is it will be save from decompile bytecode if I will use cython?

Comment: I don't know of any tools that will decompile binaries produced by Cython. But whatever format your code is in, a sufficiently determined person can work out what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like using cython will make it impossible to get script back.